# What's the IIS equivalent of these rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, iis-7, url-rewriting

I've always used apache, so I'm completely new to IIS. How would I do this in IIS?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I've got IIS Manager open, and I'm looking at "URL Rewrite" and just clicked "Add Rule(s)". I assume this is the place I want to be, but I don't know where to go from here.

---

For those of you who know IIS but not apache's mod_rewrite, it just checks if the request is NOT a directory nor a file, and if so, takes the request url and passes it to index.php as a GET param instead so that it can be handled in code, with a router.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can import them automatically, just go to the Site or Application you want and double click URL Rewrite icon, then use the Import Rules... link in the task list.
In that UI, just copy/paste the rules above and click OK, it will import those to your web.config.

The equivalent in your web.config would be (of course inside configuration/system.webServer...etc):

```
<rewrite>  
  <rules>  
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">  
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />  
      <conditions>  
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
      </conditions>  
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />  
    </rule>  
  </rules>  
</rewrite>
```

For more information on how to import them: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules/

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess lines you posted look very similar to what is used by Zend Framework.  They have a rewrite configuration guide that has [a section on IIS 7.0](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html#project-structure.rewrite.iis).